# Multiple JavaScript Modals and Closing Them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put together my website portfolio for my Advanced Graphic Design for the Web class, and I'm having an issue with JavaScript and modals.

Essentially, I have a gallery of six photos, and I want to be able to click on a photo and have a modal pop-up that's a slideshow of images (but not the other five images on the page). At the moment though, I can't get the modal to close once I add a modal to the second image. It shows up for each, but won't close. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img src="images/IMG_0722.jpg" id="Brown" class="img-responsive" alt="Van Wickle Gates">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">Brown University</div>
        </div>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="Modal1" class="modal">
            <span class="close">×</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
            <div id="caption1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img src="images/IMG_0683.jpg" id="Newport" class="img-responsive" alt="Goat Island Sunset">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">Newport</div>
        </div>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="Modal2" class="modal">
            <span class="close">×</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img02">
            <div id="caption2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('Modal1');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('Brown');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption1");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
};

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('Modal2');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('Newport');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img02");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption2");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
};

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('Modal2');
```

This code is assign  the Dom element `Modal2` **to the same** modal variable that contains `Modal1` Dom element,so you deleted the reference to the first model, and now you can't reach him and hide him from the dom.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot for missing that. Probably just from staring at the code all day. Thanks!

Comment: It's ok, happened to the best of us.
By the way, If you were using `let` instead of `var`, you would get an error: `'modal' has already been declared`. @tedmau5e

Comment: Alright, now I'm having a different problem. Even after changing all the declarations to be different for the second modal, I can't get that one to close. I've tried having just the one modal.style.display = "none", I've tried two separate ones, and I can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: @tedmau5e please ask as a separate question.